# Stack and Queue java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue

I have to create a program that follow this instructions. create a Java stack consisting of four (4) book titles entered by the user. Pop the stack's elements one by one; each popped element will be added to a queue. Then, print the content of the queue.

and here is the code I have come up but yet didn't got the desired output.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class books {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue book = new LinkedList < String > ();
        Stack < String > Title = new Stack < > ();
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter four book titles.");
        int b = 4;
        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
            System.out.print("Book " + i + ":");
            String Enter = user.nextLine();
            Title.push(Enter);
            Title.pop();
            book.offer(Title);
        }
        System.out.println("New order of books:");
        System.out.println(book);
    }
}
```

The output is something like this

```
Enter four book titles.
Book 1:b1
Book 2:b2
Book 3:b3
Book 4:b4
New order of books:
[b1, b2, b3, b4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you were doing was every time enque the whole Title stack to the queue because pop method returns the fist element to be removed from the stack

Also ....

You have to first put ALL elements in the stack and then create one more loop to add them to the queue because this way you add the first element to the stack also as first element in the queue

After `int b=4` this should be your code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=b;i++){
    System.out.print("Book " + i + ":");
    String Enter = user.nextLine();
    Title.push(Enter);
}
for(int i=1;i<=b;i++){
    book.offer(Title.pop);
}
```

instead off offer (which returns booolean) you could also use add() which throws exception if the capacity of the container is full , but your programm here is really simple so there is no way this will happen

Comment: I tried doing that, and the output was empty.

Comment: sorry my bad I edited answer right now I wrote “title” instead of “Title”

Comment: Sir, I am still having the output of empty. My println which would be the content of queue after the popping of elements, but I am having an empty queue.

Comment: Updated my answer check it out

Comment: oh, I see it should be pop right inside the queue